# how to accept Mouse Events as Touch events?

Tags: .net, wpf

How can I use the mouse as a finger, for example:

The user holds his left finger over an image side, then rotate the image by dragging the other side of image by Mouse ?

Is there an example for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can dig into Microsoft Surface SDK 2.0.  The assemblies include controls that are optimized for touch screens, but they also allow the mouse cursor to function as a single touch point.  For example, I'm using the SurfaceListBox and clicking and dragging on any item allows me to scroll.  It also does so with momentum & elasticity, giving it natural motion.

Here's the download link to Surface SDK 2.0: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26716

Comment: So, shall I use the SurfaceInkCanvas as a container for the image, to manipulate it with mouse as a touch ? is that it ? or there is a configuration for it ?

Comment: I suggest you read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx), it will tell you what the controls are capable of.  I am not entirely certain what your requirements are, but if you have a touch screen monitor, the Surface SDK is the right choice.  You don't need to use their entire framework, you can just plug-n-play controls.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are trying to do Multi Touch on a PC with just a mouse? Here's a link to doing that on a standard PC without Multi Touch.

http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2009/03/10/129993.aspx

Comment: No, I have a touch enabled screen, I need to let the mouse act like a touch input ..